# Sessions are being changed by URL changes

Tags: asp.net, session

Our **ASP.NET** website is very consistent internally in using the same URL structure to change pages.

For example: `https://mysite.org/page1.aspx` to `http://mysite.org/page2.aspx`.

We use `Session` variables to keep track of a user's logged in state. Our specific problem is a user setup a shortcut pointing to the login page as `https://www.mysite.org/LoginPage.aspx`. The `Session` variable is set to `LoggedIn=True`.

The login page then sends the user to the Homepage `http://mysite.org/homepage.aspx`.

The server creates a new session and the logged in session variable is no longer available to the new session.  How do we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your web server to redirect all requests from `www.example.com` to `example.com` (or vice-versa).
This prevents the situation from occurring in the first place.

Comment: Thanks or your quick resposne!  That's what I thought.  Exactly where is this done so I can tell out developer.